# Custom calculated field in ListBox with databinding

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm, custom-controls, calculated-field

I'm making my first Windows Phone 7 App and it's almost done, except for a calculated field in my listbox.

I have a single database with an id, a name, and an integer. I'm using the MVVM pattern. Depending on a function with some calculations, I want yo show YES or NOT as the value of the first field of my ListBox, and the second column is simple the name. How can I show the first field?

This is my code at this moment (for the listbox):

```
    <ListBox x:Name="lstPills" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="440">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="90" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border Height="36" Width="60" CornerRadius="5" Background="Grey">
                        <TextBlock Text="HERE GOES YES or NOT" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="28"/>
                    </Border>
                    <TextBlock
                        Text="{Binding Name}"
                        FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

And I have a class with the function that makes the calculation (just a example):

```
    public static bool isRight(int value)
    {
        return (Math.Abs(value) % 2 == 0 ? true : false);
    }
```

Is there some way to call this function with the bound parameter in the XAML so it reflects the result? Something like:

```
<TextBlock Text="isRight(Binding myvalue)"/>
```

I have also my Model and my ViewModel.

Comment: Just for future reference `(Math.Abs(value) % 2 == 0 ? true : false)` is the same as `(Math.Abs(value) % 2 == 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try binding this   isRight Property

```
private int _lookupValue;
public bool isRight
    {
      get {
        return (Math.Abs(_lookupValue) % 2 == 0 ? true : false);
      }
    }
```

if you think this is still not appliable then you can go with [Converters](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Collection_of_Value_converters_for_Windows_Phone_apps).

Comment: Great man, it worked perfect to set the right text value. Now comes the second problem: I must change the `<Border>` color depending on the value of isRight function, and also the `Foreground` color of the text. White for true or Black for false. How can this will be done? Maybe binding another variable to the `Background` value?

Comment: Search for Binding the Converters value.

Comment: Umm, are you telling that I can use something like this, e.g.: `<Border Background="{Binding Path=isRight, Converter={StaticResource getColor}}">` Is this? (I'm at home now, tomorrow will try).

Comment: yeh! this is what i mean.

Comment: Thanks I got it with the converters. Only a Little question about the isRight property binding: it will be called EVERY time I make a read, so if I use it in the converters, all the calcs will be done for the same item again, and again. In my example, isRight will be called (binded) for Text, ForeGround and BackGround, so the calculation will be done 3 times. Can I avoid to recalculate the same value 3 times?

Comment: Simply put a check whether a existing value is not equal.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean the last time, but it was resolved here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/28531448